# UITableViewCell not dequeued while orientation change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I find that while orientation change, `UITableView` can't dequeue a reusable cell, and must create another cell for new orientation.

Is there anyway to let `UITableView` dequeue cell regardless of orientation?

Comment: Are you using reusable dynamic prototype cells from the Storyboard and is auto layout enabled?

Comment: I've set "Identifier" in IB, and used the exact name to dequeue. I didn't use auto layout since the app targeted ios 5 and up.

Comment: I don't really have much experience on that but, did you try to call `[tableView setNeedsLayout];` or maybe `[tableView reloadData];` after orientation change takes place?

Comment: Are you sure the queue wasn't empty?